# AngularJS basics - trying to see controller variable in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm creating an mobile APP with **AngularJS** and **PhoneGap**

For now, I'm just trying to do an **ng-repeat** in my view. But **impossible** to see it. But I can see the array...

this is my controller :

```
.controller('AnnoncesController', function($scope, $http){

var ac = this;
ac.title = 'Annonces';
ac.items = [
        {ISBN:"5674789", Name: "Asp.Net MVC", Price: 560, Quantity: 20},
        {ISBN:"4352134",Name: "AngularJS", Price: 450, Quantity: 25},
        {ISBN:"2460932",Name: "Javascript", Price: 180, Quantity: 15}
    ];  
   // items

.......


  );
```

And so, my view :

```
<div ng-controller="AnnoncesController as ac">

<div>


<h1>{{ac.items}}</h1> <!-- visible -->

  <tr ng-repeat="item in ac.items"> <!-- not visible -->
     <td>
        <p> <b>{{item.Name}}</b> is in our AC.</p>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

any idea?

Comment: no errors/warnings in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2avwcL15/1/).

Simply add a `<table>` tag wrapping the `<tr>`:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in ac.items">
        <!-- not visible -->
        <td>
            <p> <b>{{ item.Name }}</b> is in our AC.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```